# how to pre-load an existing form with a data from db?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem here,so here's my code

```
        <div id="educmaininfo">
        <?php
          foreach($cv->getEducation($_GET['cvid']) as $r){
            echo "<a href='#' id='editeducation'>Edit</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='cvid' value='".$r['ResumeID']."' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='educid' value='".$r['EducationID']."'/>";
            echo "<a href='#' id='deleteeducation'>Delete</a><br />";
            echo "Date From = ".$r['DateFrom']."<br />";
            echo "Date To = ".$r['DateTo']."<br />";
            echo "Title =".$r['Title']."<br />";
            echo "Summary =".$r['Summary']."<br />";
            echo "Place Organization =".$r['PlaceOrganization']."<br />";
            echo "Emphasis of Study =".$r['EmphasisOfStudy']."<br />";
            echo "Study Details =".$r['StudyDetails']."<br />";
            echo "Qualifications =".$r['Qualifications']."<br /><br />";
          }

        ?>
       </div>
```

as you can see that code above, I added 2 hidden stuff, the cvid and the educid.
my question is, how to load this form below

```
    <div id="educajaxinfo" style="display:none">
        <table>
           <form id="educdetails" method="post" action="">
           <input type="hidden" name="cvid" id="cvid" value="<?php echo $v['ResumeID']; ?>" />
           <tr><td>Date From:</td><td><input type="text" name="datefromeduc" id="datefromeduc" value="" /></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Date To:</td><td><input type="text" name="datetoeduc" id="datetoeduc" value="" /></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="titleeduc" id="titleeduc" value="" /></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Summary:</td><td><textarea name="summaryeduc" id="summaryeduc" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Place Organization:</td><td><input type="text" name="pog" id="pog" value="" /></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Emphasis of study:</td><td><input type="text" name="eos" id="eos" value=""></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Study Details:</td><td><textarea name="studyeduc" id="studyeduc" rows="10" cols="50" ></textarea></td></tr>
           <tr><td>Qualifications:</td><td><textarea name="qualificationseduc" id="qualificationseduc" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea></td></tr>
           <tr><td><input type="submit" name="update" value="<?php if($count < 3){ echo 'Add';}else{ echo 'Update';}?>" /></td></tr>
           </form>
        </table>
    </div>
```

with the existing data from the db table, that matches the cvid and educid ?
the flow goes like this, if user clicks the edit link, it should redirect him to the
form with the values loaded in the input forms...if in pure php i can do this by just
doing something like

```
 e.g  edit.php?cvid=cvid&educid=educid
```

how to do it in ajax way?

Comment: Are you asking us to teach you AJAX?

Comment: yes am using ajax...i know a bit about jquery..but how?..so far i've done the submission of data via jquery ajax, but not sure how to do this part this time

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to call a PHP script that returns JSON encoded data. Then use the “success” callback function to inject the data into your form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery function like following

a href='#' onClick=test
 (echo  $cvid ,echo $educid ) id='editeducation'>Edit

function test(cvid,educid)
{
jQuery.post('edit.php?cvid=cvid&educid=educid',function(response){

```
        jQuery('#educajaxinfo').html(response);
    });
```

}

include the appropriate jquery min file to use above function.
on edit.php get the two id's and prepare a whole html then it will be shown in #educajaxinfo div